# How ClickOnce deploymented application works during an update while application running?

Tags: wpf, clickonce, updates

We have a wpf application, which we have deployed using Microsoft's Click Once approach...manifest and application files are available in a web server.

If the application is already running on a client machine...and if I update the manifest and application files(in web server)...how do we notify the user about the changes ?

Is there anyway that we can display some kind of text to the user...that application has modified ..and he has to get latest ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce does not provide you with an out-of-box means of alerting the end-users to an update.

In the company I worked at, it was good enough to walk around the end-users desks and making sure they weren't using the application before I updated it. Obviously, this doesn't scale too well.

If I had to implement a solution for this, I would include a message broadcast system that made sure the users were notified BEFORE the update was deployed.

If this was a client-server system, and updates to the server means that any out-of-date clients can't communicate with the server, then the end-users risk losing their work.

Comment: what about the above link that Russ gave?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.updatecheckinfo.aspx

Comment: @Anish Mohan - good point - I wasn't aware of that mechanism when I wrote the answer. However, I would still ask the question about users losing  uncommitted work from a forced update.